# Checkbox not appearing as it should

Tags: css

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/enwpbbuo/1)

```
<div class="bookmarked">
<input type="checkbox" class="addCheckItem" id="add_0">
<input type="hidden" id="bookmarkId_0" value="dsx">
<label for="add_0">Hello</label>
</div>

 .addCheckItem{
  display:none;
  float: right;
}
.addCheckItem + label:after
{
  background: #999;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
.addCheckItem:checked + label:after
{
  background: #0080FF;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Wanted the checkboxes to be hidden in visibility. Then when label is clicked, it will show tick image as selected. But css was not working, so tried basic background color first to see if it works or not. Answered found on google were already attempted but checkbox still not showing.

Not sure where I went wrong. Help appreciated.

Comment: remove that `+ label:after` from `.addCheckItem:checked` and `.addCheckItem + label:after` is not needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try the below code:**

```css
.addCheckItem{
  display:none;
}
.addCheckItem:checked + label
{
  background: url("http://www.i2symbol.com/images/symbols/check/check_mark_u2713_icon_256x256.png") no-repeat scroll right center/ 40px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bookmarkName">
<input type="checkbox" class="addCheckItem" id="add_0">
<label for="add_0">Hello</label>
<input type="hidden" id="bookmarkId_0" value="dsx">
</div>
```

Comment: Yea exactly like my answer but rearranging the mark-up. Perhaps this is a better solution since it's more precise.

Comment: @SanthoshB - erm, it is not highlighting the label text. It should show the tick mark which floats right away from label text

Comment: @joe Please check my answer now

Comment: @SanthoshB - yeah I already made it work. thanks for the answer though. I use float right while you using background position.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
.addCheckItem:checked + label:after
```

To:

```
.addCheckItem:checked ~ label
```

[Check out this blog post](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) for a good reference to CSS selectors. You used `+`

> It will select only the element that is immediately preceded by the former element. In this case, only the first paragraph after each ul will have red text.

Where `~` will select a sibling. 
If you can tell me what you intend with the `:after` selector i can maybe adjust my answer to help you better.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: :after - i wanted to have image appear when select the label text. no checkbox image. Just tick mark